# VBA take screenshot of filtered Excel and send to each row in iteration

Tags: vba, excel, email, screenshot

I want to run a Macro in Excel to loop through a number of rows, apply a filter to a spreadsheet with the name of the person, take a screenshot, and send an Email to that person with the screenshot.

My current code does not iterate through a range (only 1 record), and does not take a screenshot and insert into email.

Would greatly appreciate assistance with this.

My current code:

```
Sub SendEmailtoEachResource_Click()
' Macro  - Intended functionality
' For each person (resource) apply a filter to the 'Allocation'
' tab, and take a screenshot.  Send an email with the screenshot
' to each person.




   Dim Resoucename As String
   Dim ResouceEmail As String


   'Current State: Apply filter, and send 1 email to the below details
   ResourceName = Range("D4")
   resourceEmail = Range("E4")




   'ACTION - Future State:
                'For each person in column D
                'Send email to email address on same row in Coumn E
   '             ##Start Loop


    'Go to Allocation Tab, Apply Filter of resouce name
    Sheets("Allocation").Select
    Range("A1:BH28").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$BI$826").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        ResourceName
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 9
    Range("A1:BV836").Select

    '  ACTION: Take Screenshot of filtered results



'setup email
 Dim aOutlook As Object
    Dim aEmail As Object
    Dim outlookResName As String
    Dim SendAddress As String


    Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    outlookResName = ActiveCell.Value
    SendAddress = "me@email.com"
    aEmail.To = resourceEmail
    aEmail.Subject = "Resource assignment Report for " & ResourceName



    aEmail.HTMLBody = "Your report is below {Insert Screenshot}"
    'ACTION: Paste screenshot HERE

aEmail.display
 ' Will change to .send when VBA is working fully. This could send ~100 emails



   '  ## End LOOP




End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share an example of your data/spreadsheet?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yAJl9PYj4M-RZhdgq4mJo2UgBzG6FD-G/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please read [ask]. Providing a code dump and telling us what it doesn't do *without actually showing efforts you made to do it* is out of scope for SO, especially at the level of complexity you require. You also ask essentially 3 questions in one. I suggest you take it step-by-step and try to code each step. If you got stuck on a specific issue, post a question about that specific problem.

Comment: Apologies, and noted Scott

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have two questions rolled up in one here: (1) how to loop through the rows of your spreadsheet and (2) how to take a screenshot and insert it into the e-mail. Maybe you should consider posting two separate questions.

With that in mind, I'll address the loop issue. There are many ways to achieve what you want.

A) You could use the row numbers

```
For i = 7 To 9
    ResourceName = Cells(i, 4)
    ResourceEmail = Cells(i, 5)
    ' The rest of your code here
Next i
```

B) You could start at the first row and keep moving down until you find an empty cell.

```
i = 7
Do Until Cells(i, 4) = ""
    ResourceName = Cells(i, 4)
    ResourceEmail = Cells(i, 5)
    ' The rest of your code here
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

C) You could give the cells containing the list of resources a name (say, "resources") and loop through its rows.

```
Set MyList = ActiveWorkbook.Names("resources").RefersToRange
For Each person In MyList.Rows
    ResourceName = person.Cells(1, 4)
    ResourceEmail = person.Cells(1, 5)
    ' The rest of your code here
Next person
```

Why don't you choose one method and then we see where we go from there?

Comment: Hi Raquel. Perfect. I used C) and it is working perfectly.  I am just unsure how to get the screenshot piece working

Comment: Glad to have helped. As for the screenshot issue, I've never tried anything like that, but, since you can use the PrtScr key to take a screenshot, I believe Application.SendKeys <whatever the code for PrtScr is> should do the trick. My advice is that you give it a try first and then, if you're still stuck, post a separate question presenting your code, even if it doesn't work at all. You'll probably get more answers this way.